# Reading .txt files in Java using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm using a `BufferedReader` to read a `.txt` files from Java but it acts strange. Some files are read normally and some return few empty lines and null or skips first few lines of text and prints rest. I checked paths, encoding, attributes, everything is the same in those files that I'm trying to read but code read one file and other wont.

```
System.out.println("\r\nChose desired shelf:");
String shelf = br.readLine();
FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\admir\\MyBookLibrary\\"+shelf+"\\Info.txt");
BufferedReader info = new BufferedReader(fr);
while(info.readLine() != null) {
    System.out.println(info.readLine());
}
fr.close();
info.close();
```

Comment: You are calling `info.readLine()` twice - one in while loop condition and one inside loop body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code has `info.readLine()` twice, it will skip printing alternate lines for all the files. 
It is possible that for files that are getting printed correctly you have an empty line or linefeed character `\n` after each line of text, and coincidently that is being skipped.
In the other files also, it must be skipping alternate lines.
Can you check the actual content of your files.

I have modified your code slightly and it works now:

```
System.out.println("\r\nChose desired shelf:");
String shelf = br.readLine();
FileReader fr = new 
FileReader("D:\\admir\\MyBookLibrary\\"+shelf+"\\Info.txt");
BufferedReader info = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;
while((line = info.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
fr.close();
info.close();
```

Comment: You are correct.It is actually because some files had empty lines between text and other files didnt.I did checked this.Could you give me code snippet or advice how to read files like this without calling readLine() twice,because i tryed to type without readLine() and i got error.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are reading lines with `readLine()` twice which means you will print every second line. Also you should use try-with-resource to manage your `AutoCloseable` objects:

```
String shelf = br.readLine();
Path path = Paths.get("D:", "admir", "MyBookLibrary", shelf, "Info.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
  br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: I tryed this way.But with this code it wont read any of my files.I know im calling readLine twice but im confused why it reads some files and some wont.

Comment: My code works for text files. Attach your file to your question and we can see why, perhaps you are attempting to read a binary file as a text?